# How do I see where my IDE is trying to look up packages?

Tags: python, import, package

I am using Spyder IDE on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Buster. I trying to create a sort of computer vision program using OpenCV. I have installed OpenCV in the past and this works fine. I am now trying to use audio and decided to use the SimpleAudio package. I installed this successfully in the following path:

```
pip install simpleaudio
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: simpleaudio in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.4)
```

Although when I try and import simpleaudio, I get the following error message in Spyder:

```
 File "/home/pi/FYP/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    import simpleaudio.functionchecks as fc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpleaudio'
```

I have a feeling this is due to the fact that simpleaudio is installed in the wrong directory or Spyder is looking for it in the wrong directory.

Due to the fact that I have installed OpenCV previously and the import statement works for this, should simpleaudio should be in the same directory as this package? If this is correct, how do I find out where Spyder is looking for packages to fix this issue?

UPDATE:
I have found out where OpenCV is installed:

```
runfile('/home/pi/FYP/temp.py', wdir='/home/pi/FYP')
<module 'cv2' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so'>
```

Why in this case is there two different areas where packages are located? Should I manually pip install simpleaudio into this location? I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed (ie. 2.7 and 3.7) and `pip` may install modules for one Python but you run code with other Python. Check `pip -V` and `pip3 -V`. You may have also `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.7`, `pip3.6` to install modules for different Pythons. The same with Python: `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python3`, `python3.7`, (`python3.8`, `python3.6`)

Comment: BTW: messages show you installed `simpleaudio` for `Python 3.6` (and it is also anaconda distribution which uses `conda` to install) but you run `OpenCV` with `Python3.7`

Comment: Thank you for your message. I have been going through a lot of trial and error getting Python, Spyder and Pip installed and as I suspected, I have installed more than one version. I am still unsure how I would fix this though. As OpenCV is with Python 3.7 and Simpleaudio 3.6.

Comment: to install for `python 3.7`  use `pip3.7 install ...` or `python3.7 -m pip install ...`